# Building TASM32 SDK?

Tags: sdk, masm32, tasm

I just downloaded Embarcadero Delphi 2010 (the trial version).
tasm32 and the related stuffs (ilink32, implib, impdef, etc) are still available in it.
Still they lack header files and import libs, but fortunately that can be solved by win2inc, implib, etc.

The final result can be called TASM32 SDK (in a similar way like MASM32 SDK do).

Considering Delphi is a commercial product, I plan to use this SDK for personal usage only (and of course non commercially).

Is this legal or not?

Comment: In case of doubt just ask embarcadero. They should be able to give a authorized answer. If Embarcadero does allow you the using, then it is legal.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is this legal or not?"

That depends on the country.

Also, "legality" doesn't have a binary yes/no value (instead the result may depend on arguments made in a court of law, if the question ever even goes to court).

Comment: Ouch. 
Guess I have to switch to another assembler.
And I also heard maintaining header files isn't an easy job to do...